# Knockout complex nested object binding using mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am facing issue in binding a knockout object created using the mapping plugin of Knockout.js.

Single level attributes are mapped accessible as usual. But multiple level object attributes are not accessible. I cannot understand why?

HTML file:

```
message is: <span data-bind="text: myMessage"></span> 
<span data-bind="with: myMsg"><span data-bind="text: ab"></span></span> 
<span data-bind="foreach: arr"><span data-bind="text: z"></span></span>
```

JS file:

```
var viewModel = {
    myMessage: "Hello, world!",
    arr: [{z: 1}],
    myMsg: {
        ab: 'hhi'
    }
};

var k = ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModel);

alert(k.myMsg.ab());
alert(k.arr()[0].z());

ko.applyBindings(k);
```

Here's a JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/pbheed/badZb/37/

Comment: I have updated the KO version in your fiddle to the latest 2.2.1. And it is working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/UXV4S/ ...

Comment: By the way that KO version (2.0.0) is not compatible with JQuery 2.0 so if you change the jQuery to 1.7.2 in your original fiddle it is also working...